# R, get entires from one column based on values of another column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to get column entries as a list that match a list of entries from data frame

Showing what I am trying to do:

Dataframe named `Tepo`
|  | name | shortcut |

| -------- | -------------- | ----------|

| 1    | Apples            | A |

| 2   | Bannans            | B |

| 3    | oranges            | O |

| 4   | Carrots            | C |

| 5    | Mangos            | M |

| 6   | Strawberies           | S |

I have a list `FruitList` as chr

```
>FruitList
>[1] "Bannas" "Carrots" "Mangos"
```

And I would like to get a list, `shortcutList`, of the corresponding columns:

```
>shortcutList
>[1] "B" "C" "M"
```

My attempt:

```
shortcutList <- tepo$shorcut[tepo$name == FruiteList[]]
```

However, I don't get the desired list output.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `%in%` :

```
shortcutList <- tepo$shortcut[tepo$name %in% FruitList]
```